# Jquery Opacity Fade In Out Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

One of my clients asked me to make a blinking effect on a div. I think that might not be the best thing for him, maybe light fading in and out of opacity will get the attention of his customers, without annoying them.

I currently have

```
 <a class="special_button" href="#">Special Offers &rsaquo;</a>
```

I have the following code for another div, which causes a fade in on browser load :

```
$('.logo-top').delay(700).animate({
     'opacity' : '1',        
     'top' : '+=40px'
}, { duration: 700, easing: 'swing' });
```

How would I do something similar for the special_button, but instead looping the opacity? From say 80 to 100?

It would even be better if it looped a certain amount of times, maybe like 5.

Best,
Stepan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to have something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLMp8/26/).

And you can also indicate the number of times you want this to blink, just by keeping a counter.

Code from jsFiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     function runIt() {           
       var baloon = $('#baloon');
       baloon.animate({opacity:'1'}, 1000);
       baloon.animate({opacity:'0.5'}, 1000, runIt);
    }
    runIt();
});
```

Comment: Hi Ulan, this worked excellently! Thanks for the help -- It came out much better than I would have thought.

Comment: These values are not necessary (`'+=1'` and `'-=0.5'`) because opacity can never be more than `1` nor less than `0`. A mere `'1'` and `'0.5'` should suffice.

Comment: Just searched and stumbled on this.Thanks a bunch, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

Why not use CSS3 keyframes?

```css
.twinkle {
  background: red;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 50px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes twinkly {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0.4;}
}

@-moz-keyframes twinkly {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0.4;}
}

@-ms-keyframes twinkly {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0.4;}
}

@keyframes twinkly {
  from {opacity: 1;}
  to {opacity: 0.4;}
}

.twinkle {
  -webkit-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
  -moz-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
  -ms-animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
  animation: twinkly 1s alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<span class="twinkle">Special Offers &rsaquo;</span>
```

You can use a fallback for older browsers then. Any of the scripts the other propsed are good but I would advise Ulan's solution.

Comment: And you just leveled up my CSS3 :). Thanks Bram

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this;

```
(function() {
    var cnt = 0;
    var specials = $(".special_button");

    function next() {
        if (cnt < 5) {
            specials.fadeTo(2000, .1).fadeTo(2000, 1, next);
            ++cnt;
        }                    
    }

    next();
})();
​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/558GY/

FYI, the difference between 80% and 100% opacity is pretty subtle.  I made the difference much greater in the demo.  You can obviously tune to whatever effect you want.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll show this demo to the client as well . Thanks jfriend :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you want something flashing here its:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    anm(".special_button");
});
function anm(element) {
    $(element).delay(200).animate({ opacity: 'toggle' }, 1000, function() { anm(element); });
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/GdcRs/

Answer (score 1):

if you like short code then you use the [plugin jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) for timing stuff in jQuery.
It shrinks your complete code to:

```
$('#baloon').repeat().fadeTo(1000,1).fadeTo(1000,0.5,$);
```

Oh, and when you want it to toggle a specific number of times (e.g. 20), then you write

```
$('#baloon').repeat().fadeTo(1000,1).fadeTo(1000,0.5,$).until(20);
```

Cool, eh?